# Calculate StandardDeviation with linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to calculate the StandardDeviation in a linq query with the following code:

```
EntityFunctions.StandardDeviation(context.Results.Select(r => r.Score))
```

But this gives the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not         handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

How can i calculate the StandardDeviation with linq to entities?

Comment: I don't think so, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382955(v=vs.110).aspx "This function is translated to a corresponding function in the database."

Comment: Actually, if you're using Entity Framework you could try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.standarddeviation%28v=vs.113%29.aspx - I could't get it working though

Comment: What is the type of `Score`?

Comment: `Score` is a `double`